# UML use case diagram problem with relations between actors and use cases

Tags: uml, use-case

i've been created the following diagram for forums system but i'm not sure if the relation between use cases and actors is correct.

so i want to know if my diagram is correct or if i've added too much complexity to my diagram. did i got my use cases relation with the actors correctly? well to better say, is it correct at all?

[image]

any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a bad effort for a first attempt, but I'd say it is a bit over complex. When you do analysis, using use cases or some other method, you really do want to keep it simple and avoid going into design mode, which is when you start thinking about relationships between things.

In my opinion, your actors should not be generalizations of one another. A "person who posts" on a forum is not a a more specific type of a "person who reads posts": they are different roles which the same person might take on at different times, not expansions on one another. So I'd advise you to drop those generalizations.

The same goes for the use cases themselves. Normally, use cases relate to one another by way of either the `<<extend>>` or `<<include>>` relationship, but generalizations or not normally used. Use cases aren't like classes and don't really have the option of being abstract, so the "manage" use cases need to make sense on their own, and they don't really do that. Your "concrete" use cases, on the other hand, make perfect sense.

In order to group related use cases together, it's a better idea to use separate diagrams and / or gather the use cases into packages called "post management", "site administration", etc. There is nothing which says you have to put all your use cases into a single diagram.

Answer (score 0):

I support your method of use case diagrams.  I struggled with this very issue a while back.  To show each association from one use case to each of the actors was getting messy.  By generalizing the actors, it consolidated the associations into a nice, easily readable format.  Thus, the information is easier for others to consume.